# Refrescar una página con PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una solicitud a la base de datos, para actualizar o eliminar un campo, según lo que desee el usuario. El problema que se presenta es que cuando ejecuta la consulta guarda los valores pero no actualiza la página, sino es hasta pulsa f5 para recargar.

```
<a href="index.php?id='<?php echo $di;?>'" class="confirm" title="Confirm Accomodation"> Confirm </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="index.php?di='<?php echo $di ?>'" class="cancel" title="Cancel Accomodation"> Cancel </a>

         <?php
             if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

                $get = $_GET['id'];

                $update = "UPDATE notification SET state='1', confirmed='1' WHERE id_not = $get";
                $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $update);
             }

             else if (isset($_GET['di'])) {

                 $get = $_GET['di'];

                 $drop = "DELETE FROM notification WHERE id_not = $get";
                 $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $drop);
             }
          ?>
```

Quiero que cuando el usuario oprima alguno de estos botones (confirmar o cancelar), aparte de que ejecuten la consulta se refresque la página al momento de finalizar, si me pueden ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te puede servir, ponlo despues de actualizar los campos:

```
parent.window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la intervención, pero no me fuincionó, intenté de esta manera y si funcionó:

```
<a href="index.php?id='<?php echo $di;?>'" class="confirm" title="Confirm Accomodation"> Confirm </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="index.php?di='<?php echo $di ?>'" class="cancel" title="Cancel Accomodation"> Cancel </a>

      <?php
          if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

             $get = $_GET['id'];

             $update = "UPDATE notification SET state='1', confirmed='1' WHERE id_not = $get";
             $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $update);
       ?>
       <script> location.reload();</script>

       <?php
             }

              else if (isset($_GET['di'])) {

              $get = $_GET['di'];

              $drop = "DELETE FROM notification WHERE id_not = $get";
              $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $drop);
        ?>

        <script> location.reload();</script>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` Esto es una funcion de php, asique no abras script de js, hazlo desde el mismo if o donde lo vayas a querer, aver si te funciona